# Httpd only allows to access files that are directly created in the /var/www/html folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, httpd.conf, rhel7

I'm using Httpd for the first time and the final goal is to setup a wordpress instance on a local RHEL server (that has no external internet access).
So I installed httpd via `yum` and used `touch hello.html` inside the `/var/www/html` folder which worked fine and the file is available via browser. Now I started to move a html file from another computer via `winScp` to the root directory of the server and moved it with `mv` to the folder. I did also use `chmod` to set the correct access rights, but it didn't work.

How can I setup the server to serve these files? Atm I receive an `403 Forbidden` error, so I assume I have to do something within the httpd config?

Would be very thankful for any help to get me onboard!

Comment: What directory will web pages be served from?

Comment: They should be served from the root folder, like http://<MY_IP>/hello.html

Comment: http://<MY_IP>/hello.html  is not an indication of where the page is served from. It's the document root I'm asking about. Typically apache serves pages from `/var/www`. Where do you intend to serve web pages from?

Comment: Ah sorry I missed your point. As far as I know files from the /var/www/html folder? all the files I touched in that folder directly are also served directly under the IP I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to use a `VirtualHost`, and put the configuration in sites-enabled directory. You can of course just edit your httpd.conf and put the configuration in there. It's just not as flexible for administration.

Edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` using `sudo`.

Add `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` at end of httpd.conf. Save and exit.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-enabled /etc/httpd/sites-available
```

Using `sudo`, edit `/etc/httpd/sites-available/mysite.conf and add the following`VirtualHosts` block:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName mysite.domain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now create the link for the config to the sites-enabled directory

sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/mysite.conf /etc/http/sites-enabled

To restart Apache after completing the above, do

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

The alternative is to add the VirtualHost block directly in `httpd.conf`, then re-start Apache.